# Putty, Byobu, Tmux and function keys

Tags: shortcut-keys, byobu, putty, function-keys, tmux

I'm currently trying to use byobu from PuTTY via ssh. I have currently `putty-256color` as `Terminal-type string` because otherwise not even Byobu bindings worked and I couldn't create new windows or move between them. I have Tmux backend and `byobu-crtl-a` set to `emacs` however I can't seem to make F keys work in either Midnight Commander or htop. I tried as suggested the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to enable them but I receive no message and still can't make them work.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 17):

After reading it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150311105915/http://choorucode.com/2013/01/21/byobu-function-keys-do-not-work-in-putty) I changed the session so that "Terminal → Keyboard" has the option "Xterm R6" selected.

Comment: Using Xterm R6 restores F1 and F2 key functionality but Shift-F1 and Shift-F2 seem to be interpreted as sending character "~". Client is putty on windows 10, server is ubuntu 16.04